# CSS - Responsive div with background

Tags: css

I have the following:-

```
<div id="join-container"></div>

    #join-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        background: url(../img/work-for-us-header.jpg);
    }
```

I want to make this responsive so the height adjusts as I shrink the browser, I've tried remove the width and height and adding background-size: 100%; but this doesn't display any image.

Can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try background-size: contain;

Comment: `background-size: contain` or `background-size: cover`, depending: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: @cale_b `cover` might not work for him. because solution needs to be responsive. so it might not show whole background, depending on viewport size.

Comment: @devtye - understood, wanted to provide plenty of resource, not just the "answer" per-se.

Comment: @cale_b no problem, just making sure

Comment: background-size: contain; would only work if there is content inside this div, join-container has no content when < 768px so when applying any of the above, the background image just disappears

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padding-bottom` **BUT** you must determine the aspect-ratio of the image.

`padding-bottom` is relative to the width of the container. So if your image's aspect ratio is **16:9** then the your container should be:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 9/16 = .5625 */
  background: transparent url('http://www.freelargeimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Landscape_01.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/awqbLukm/

When you resize the browser, your padding-bottom will resize proportionally to the width of the container.

Now if you intend to place some other contents inside this box, you can just create another `div` which is positioned absolutely inside this `#container` and set its `width` and `height` to `100%`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to display your background. It doesn't require content inside of the element, to get `background-size: contain` to work. your problem is your height is going by pixels, this doesn't support your responsiveness of your element.

It is best to use either percentage or viewport height. Beware that viewport-height isn't supported by all browsers.

**Example 1**: keep your background centered and fit into the boundaries of your element, and also keep your background proportional.

```
<div id="join-container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#join-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1000x500') no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position: center; 
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

**Example 2:** always fill the element with the background. Drawback is it might skew your image.

```
<div id="join-container_2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#join-container_2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1000x500') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center; 
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/mmru9m9o/
Play with viewport size.

If you really have to keep the div height in pixels, you might want to start thinking about media queries. You check that out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score -1):

meh, just use img.

```
<img style='width:100%;height:100%;' src='cat.png'>
```

or if you must...

```
<div class="bla">
</div>

.bla{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background:  url(../img/work-for-us-header.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```